# Close Question?

Tags: discussion

Should we close this question https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/problem-solving-work-teams-vs-self-managing-work-teams?

How much time should we wait for the OP to fill in further details?

My vote is to close after 24-48 hours (but not less than 1 day).

Comment: One to two days seems reasonable to me. Questions are rarely "hot" after a couple of days...except maybe questions asked on a Friday afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should go ahead and close this question, it has been more than long enough.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about closing it, but I knew no one would try to answer it because there just really isn't enough information in the question to even remotely post anything helpful as an answer, so I left it alone for now.

Had it been one of those questions that would build a list or generate a lot of actively harmful spam, I'd probably have taken initiative on it much *much*  sooner.

Looking at the op's profile, it looks like he was just on 3 hours ago, so maybe he's off doing some research on the topic himself so he can provide some more details. In this case, I think it's wise, and reasonable, to wait a day or two to see if he comes back with some nice updates.

Of course, this shouldn't stop anyone with 500+ rep from taking action on it by voting to close, since it takes 5 to close. As a moderator, I'm trying to only intervene when it's more beneficial to close right away than it is to leave something be. The more our community shows it polices itself without a diamond moderator getting involved, the healthier and stronger we'll become! :)  Hope this helps!